# Microservices: detecting a failed service ( root of all problems )

Tags: microservices

I would like to understand how to detect the failed service ( in a fast / reliably manner ), ie the service what is a root of all 5xx responses?

Let me try to elaborate. Lets assume we have 300+ microservices and they have only synchroneous http interaction via GET request without any data modifications ( we assume it for simplicity ). Each customer request may transform in calling ~10 different microservices, moreover it could be a 'calling chain' of requests, ie API Gateway calls 3 different microservices, each of them calls 1-5 more, each of these 1-5 calls 1-5 more etc.

We closely monitor 5xx errors on each of microservice and react on these errors.

Now one of the microservices fails. It appears to be somewhere in the end of a 'calling chain', which means that other microservices which depend on it will start to return 5xx as well.

Yes, there are circuit breakers, yes they become 'triggered / opened' and instead of calling the downstream service, they right away return error as well ( in most cases we cannot return a good fallback like empty response ).

So we see that relatively big amount of microservices return 5xx. Like 30-40 microservices return 5xx, we see 30-40 triggered / opened circuit breakers.

How to detect a failed microservice, a root of all evil, in a fast manner?
Did anybody encounter this issue?

Regards

Comment: You can create request-id in starting point (client request), write logs to elk stack(or analogue), and then scrape result, for example, give me first exception for given request-id.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a distributed tracing solution that tracks the origin transaction with a global ID. The name of this global identifier is typically called Correlation ID and it is generated by the very first service which creates the request and propagated to all the other microservices that work together to fulfill the request.

Take a look at [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/) for your implementation needs. It provides libraries for you to add the instrumentation required for identifying faulty microservices in a distributed environment.

However, if you really do have 300 microservices all using synchronous calls...maybe it is time to consider using asynchronous communications to eliminate the temporal coupling inherent in synchronous communications.